# jQuery fade - Display div on page load

Tags: jquery, fade

I have a simple jquery fade working perfectly, I am trying to have it so that when the page is opened the first div is displayed automatically.

Currently when the page loads there is no content

http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/10/

```
 $(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

Comment: When the page loads there is no content? You mean the content in `.content-container`? That is because you trigger the event when you click on a link. You need to trigger this event on page load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Till now you are registering the click events for every link by this code

```
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

What i suggest is to fire the click once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute

So try this with your code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".link")[0].click(); 
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttj9J/)

Answer (score 1):

Just execute .show() function when the DOM is fully loaded:

```
$(function() {
     $('#content1').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/11/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#' + $('a:eq(0)').data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');

$(".link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/Wqc9N/17/)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I did'nt find any difficulty there to show the first div

```
$('#content1').fadeIn('slow');
$(".link").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

[**Updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/18/#update)